# Release-Only form of CAS

Tags: java, jvm, compare-and-swap, kamon

I have accidentally run into [Striped64.java](https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/blob/master/kamon-core/src/main/java/kamon/jsr166/Striped64.java) class from Kamon Monitoring tool. At line 95 I found this comment:

```
JVM intrinsics note: It would be possible to use a release-only
form of CAS here, if it were provided.
```

Although I understand what CAS is, I am unable to find out what a ***release-only form of CAS*** is. Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: As a side note, this class is *not* kamon specific; it is present in the jdk-8/9 also under `java.util.concurrent.atomic`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am unable to find out what a release-only form of CAS is.

That refers to memory ordering constraints on atomics in the terms of the [C++ memory model](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order). Some of those are not fully expressible in the terms of the [java memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) which predates the C++ one (see also [the JMM cookbook for developers](https://giltene.github.io/DeveloperJMMCookbook/)) and thus they are currently not made available through the standard library.

This will change with Java9 where [varhandles](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html) will expose memory accesses that match C++ semantics, except consume order.

Also note that the java class you linked has been copied from the jsr166 repository, which is the upstream version of the JDK j.u.c. packages.

Comment: what you actually mean is a CAS with release semantics only? If so then wouldn't this be possible on *other* cpu's but x86 (since a cas is translated to `lock cmpxchg`, thus a full fence)?

Comment: @Eugene yes... was that unclear? CAS is one of the atomic memory accesses, but not the only one.

Comment: at this point I don't know if you are mocking me or not, but still... The argument about varhandles is about misleading *for me*. This method is present since 1.8: `public native void storeFence`; so it seems you could do the StoreStore + LoadStore and have the release semantics. Totally forgot, 1+

Comment: @Eugene no mocking intended. so to clarify:  a) fences cannot *weaken* the acquire-release of the CAS that's currently available in sun.misc.Unsafe. b) fences are fairly blunt instruments that impose more constraints than ordered atomics *on specific memory locations*, i.e. ordered accesses and fences are not equivalent.

Comment: this goes a bit too far from my comfort/understanding zone; but the main idea was understood. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Normally for a volatile write you will get the following barriers

```
[StoreStore]
[LoadStore]
x=10
[StoreLoad]
```

The StoreLoad has 2 purposes:

- it prevents newer loads to float above x=10.
- it makes all changes that happend before 'x=10' visible on other processors.

The StoreLoad is potentially expensive since it waits for the store buffer to get drained.

The above approach, in combination with the following for the read of X

```
tmp=x
[LoadLoad]
[LoadStore]
```

Will make sure that accessing a volatile variable is sequential consistent.

A **release only form** would look like this

```
[StoreStore]
[LoadStore]
x=10
```

As you can see the [StoreLoad] barrier is gone.

On the reading side, it is the same as a regular volatile read.

I don't know how 'release-only form of CAS' fits into the picture

And like the8472 already indicated, the new VarHandles in Java 9 will expose the relaxed 'acquire/release' ordering guarantees.

Comment: I think the barrier notation is not quite correct since it is simply a conservative approximation of the real JMM semantics. A JVM could be more aggerssive than that and use memory-location-specific ordering. On weakly ordered architectures that means using ordered load or store instructions on an individual variable instead of issuing barrier instructions which order all memory accesses. that can have an  impact on the global order (or lack thereof) observed if there are more than 2 threads.

Comment: The barrier notation is a direct reflection of how it is expressed in the Javadoc.  e.g "Sets the value of a variable to the newValue, and ensures that prior loads and stores are not reordered after this access." http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#setRelease-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: Ah right, those only cover thread-local reorderings and java doesn't do consume order either.

Comment: I agree with your initial point that the notation isn't quite correct. I got fooled into using barriers as a replacement for the JMM. What bugs me however is that the line becomes very thin. In the case of an acquire/release, the specification is expressed in such fences.